# std::function, it must have template argument?

Tags: c++

```
void hello(float i)
{
    std::cout << "hello" << i << "\n";
}

int hollo(int a)
{
    std::cout << "good" << a;
    return 0;
}

int main(int, char**)
{
    std::function hallo = hello;
    hallo(3.0f);
    
    hallo = hollo;
    hallo(3);
    
    while (true) {}
}
```

My code above works.

First, can I really use `std::function` without inserting a template argument, unlike internet examples?

Second, does this way of not using the template argument have any bad effects (decreasing performance, making the code hard to be managed and checked for type, or anything)?

Or, did it have any good effect (yea, I can make any function get into `std::function` only using `=`, it makes me happy)?

Comment: C++ is an language that is still evolving.  Those examples that you have seen are using and older version of C++ that does not have [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) which allows you to omit the template parameters. Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Note that your program has undefined behavior. You are not allowed to have an infinite loop which doesn't do any atomic/volatile/IO or similar operation.

Answer (score 5):

> Can I use std::function without inserting template argument

Yes and no. `std::function` is a class template, and it must have template arguments, but (since C++17) those template arguments may be deduced from the function arguments of the constructor, in which case you don't have to specify the template arguments explicitly.

```
// deduced as std::function<void(float)>
std::function hallo = hello;

// no deduction; ill-formed
std::function broken;
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answer says why this is allowed, but I want to mention that not specifying template arguments may cause readability issues sometimes. For example in the code you have shown, what do you expect the second call `hallo(3);` to do?

I assume you think that simply `hollo` is called with argument `3`, but that is not the case. The type of `hallo` was deduced as `std::function<void(float)>` and that doesn't change in the assignment `hallo = hollo;`. So, actually, the argument `3` is first cast to `float` and then passed to `hollo` which implies that it is cast back to `int` again. These casts may change the value that ends up as the `hollo` argument. (Although very likely not for the value `3` specifically.)

Similarly you may expect `hallo(3)` to return an `int`, but it doesn't since the deduced function type for `std::function` has return type `void`.